# cant pass the object state as prop

Tags: reactjs

I'm practising React with doing a Face Recognition app while following a course. As summary, the below component should create a `div` with `style=` properties top,right,bottom and left.

```
const FaceRecognition = ({imageUrl,box}) => {
    console.log("hello",box.rightCol);
    return (
        <div className="center ma">
            <div className="absolute mt2">
        <img id="inputimage" alt="" src={imageUrl} width="500px" height="auto"/>
        <div style={{top: box.topRow, right: box.rightCol, bottom: box.bottomRow, left: box.leftCol}} className="bounding-box"></div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But the problem is, when i check the body of the page, i cant see the `style` properties that i gave.

[image]

I checked the `state and props` for being sure is everything ok while passing the object, below is the function for using setState,

```
  displayFaceBox = (box) =>{
    console.log(box);
    this.setState=({box: box});
    console.log(this.state.box);
  }
```

Everything seems OK to here. These two console.log function gives below logs. (`box` seems alright but `state box` seems not):

[image]

I am not sure this causes the problem, but i couldn't figure out how can i pass the `box` prop to `FaceRecognition component` with top, right, bottom and left attributes. You can find the other details below.

Below part sends response to displayFaceBox function to setting the state.

```
  fetch("https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/" + MODEL_ID + "/outputs", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(response => {
    const parser = JSON.parse(response);
    this.displayFaceBox(this.calculateFaceLocation(parser));
  })
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  }
```

And calculateFaceLocation returns an object.

```
  calculateFaceLocation = (data) => {
    const clarifaiFace = data.outputs[0].data.regions[0].region_info.bounding_box;
    const image = document.getElementById("inputimage");
    const width = Number(image.width);
    const height = Number(image.height);
    return {
      leftCol: clarifaiFace.left_col * width,
      topRow : clarifaiFace.top_row * height,
      rightCol : width-(clarifaiFace.right_col*width),
      bottomRow : height - (clarifaiFace.bottom_row*height),
    }
  }
```

Comment: I looks like you were using this component in two places

Comment: a parent component could pass props to it's child components
but the child components themselves can't pass props to each other 
they don't even know they coexist in the same parent component 
i just wanted to mention that maybe it helps i couldn't figure out why you are not getting the styles correctly

i'd say try putting the style object into a variable then pass it to the style attribute maybe it will help

Comment: i figured out now. there is just a syntax error in setState method.  "this.setState=({box: box});" because of the equal sign i couldnt set the state, state is blank. and because of this, i pass the state as empty prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is not set properly .

`setState` syntax is `setState(...)`.

You are referring it as `setState=(...)`.

Because of which the state is not set and you are sending `empty prop`.

Try changing

```
  displayFaceBox = (box) =>{
    console.log(box);
    this.setState=({box: box});
    console.log(this.state.box);
  }
```

to

```
  displayFaceBox = (box) =>{
    console.log(box);
    this.setState({box: box});
    console.log(this.state.box);
  }
```